# How can i get full home using different parts of images in php?

Tags: php, jquery

[front panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WNGs.png)    [final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLB4r.png)

I have to make full home with 4 different parts i.e front,side, roof and stand like above image which has 3 differnt option in each panel. How can i preview every selected panel image and also get panel id to create a full home image using php.I want to create complete house by selecting particular panel.

Thanks in advance

```
                <div class="row top">
               <div class="container">
                  <div class="wel-grids">
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 wel-grid wow fadeInDown">
                        <div class="wel11">
                           <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="F1" onClick="changeSrc()">
                           <label  for="radio1"  style="font-size:12px; cursor: pointer;">
                           <img  style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" class="img-responsive" src="images/Ppicture2.png"></label>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 wel-grid wow fadeInDown">
                        <div class="wel11">
                           <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="F1" onClick="changeSrc()" >
                           <label for="radio2"  style="font-size:12px; cursor: pointer;  ">
                           <img style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" class="img-responsive" src="images/Ppicture3.png"></label>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 wel-grid wow fadeInDown">
                        <div class="wel11">
                           <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="F1" onClick="changeSrc()">
                           <label for="radio3"  style="font-size:12px; cursor: pointer;  ">
                           <img style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" class="img-responsive" src="images/PPpicture2.png"></label>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <br>

            <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeSrc() {
    if (document.getElementById("radio1").checked) {
    document.getElementById("picture").src = "images/Ppicture3.png";
    } else if (document.getElementById("radio2").checked) { 
    document.getElementById("picture").src = "images/Ppicture2.png";
    }
else if (document.getElementById("radio3").checked) { 
    document.getElementById("picture").src = "images/PPpicture2.png";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what you had tried ?

Comment: i have tried with radio button and followed by  document.getElementById() ,but its not working in all panel as the same javascript keep repeating.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Hey Mayank, added code also. Please check now. I am breaking my head over this;-(

Comment: show your code what you have tried,

Comment: Its better if you make one fiddle with your fully code so we can get idea properly

Comment: Edited above full code that i have tried with and also attached front panel screen shot .Please check

Comment: I have attached front panel and final complete home image which has to be made dynamically.I couldn't get any idea how to make it happen.If anybody suggest how to get it done would be appreciated